# Aws amplify federated sign in trough iframe 'X-Frame-Options' to 'deny'

Tags: amazon-cognito, aws-amplify

Is there a way to call `Auth.federatedSignIn({  provider: CognitoHostedUIIdentityProvider.Facebook });` inside iframe but from new tab(window)?

I've tried to add link with `targe=_top` or `target=_blank` but that didn't solved my problem. I mean I need to open new window with cognito hosted UI? Though if link is clicked outside of iframe everything works properly..